# How to develop Googlecast device?

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I want to know how to make a google supported device like chromecast audio
and how to get device development SDK if it is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you read [tour] and [ask] you'll see that this site is for asking and answering specific programming questions.  For getting started and tutorial help you'll need to do a web search to find other sites like CodeProject for Windows that cover that.

Comment: To help you start with, you can visit the documentation of [Google Cast](https://developers.google.com/cast/). Also try to explore the [this page](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_overview) for the device management. "CAF Receiver SDK is a major upgrade from the Receiver v2 SDK. Improvements focus on significantly reducing the amount of code required to implement a receiver app, while making Cast more reliable to maintain. This was done by implementing all common use cases into CAF."